# Ending Date Discrepancy Mistake on Resume and Background Check - 1 year

Tags: resume, job-offer, background-check, start-date, mistakes

I recently received an offer for a fantastic entry-level job and they are running a background check, which is taking longer than expected. So much so that my start date was pushed back. Today, I noticed an accidental typo on my resume that transferred to the 3rd party background check. It listed my ending date of a part-time high school job a year later than it actually was. For example, it says 2012 instead of 2011. I have been in contact with HR, who asked if I had a W-2 or pay stub for this job OR a different job I had in college. I was able to provide the info for the college job, but not high school, as it was 5/6+ years ago. Plus, the specific franchise I worked at is no longer in existence.

I have not told them about the discrepancy, as I did not know about it at the time they called. I have been advised by several people not to mention it unless they bring it up to me and then be totally honest about my mistake. However, I am concerned they will pull my offer. Has anyone been in a similar situation or know of someone who has? If so, what happened?

Also, I know there have been similar questions, but most have only had dates off by a month or so. Those answers haven't given me much to go off of. AND I am very aware this was a MAJOR fail on my part.

Comment: Regarding the tax paperwork (which I assume you mean) or pay stubs, keep in mind that the tax man can typically come after you for details for several years after taxes have been filed. If you haven't been saving those religiously before, at least start doing so right now. Stop by at a book store or an office supply store and get yourself a binder or whatever else fits your needs for this, and place *all* paperwork that is in any way relevant for taxes in it. Check to see for how long you may be required to keep them, then add another year or two for safety before you throw *any* of it away.

Comment: They are more likely to believe it is an innocent mistake, rather than intentional deception, if they hear about it from you rather than finding it out themselves. They may not care, but in that case telling them makes no difference.

Comment: By deleting this post, you are doing a disservice to mutt, who has taken the time to help you by posting a well-thought-out answer. I suggest you roll back your edit to its previous state.

Comment: I've rolled back the question; we don't delete questions here just because they've been answered. If there is a really strong reason you don't think this question should stay around to help others, please flag it for moderator attention and explain why.

Answer (score 1):

The forms usually say to the best of my knowledge.  Human mistakes are part of the process.  I would disclose this information asap to the employer as an accidental mistake on the documentation.  Also depending on the type of background check you may be asked by someone about it and you can disclose it to them as well.  Someone that doesn't disclose it will likely appear they are trying to bloat their experience by a year.  It may not matter at all, but it's better to show yourself honest even with your mistakes than appear like a liar at the beginning.

If they already liked you and offered to you, then chances are it will only be a good character move to disclose your honest mistake.